# Property '__docgenInfo' does not exist on type 'string' for React Child

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm passing in children to a React component and using this line of code to see if a 'Button' type component has been passed in as a child.

```
export type ExampleComponentProps = {
 children: React.ReactNode;
}

export const ExampleComponent: React.FC<ExampleComponentProps> = ({children}) => { 

const hasButtons = React.Children.toArray(children).some((child) => 
 React.isValidElement(child) && child.type._docgenInfo.displayName === 'Button');

console.log(hasButton); //true

 return ( 
  <>{children}</>
 ) 
};

<ExampleComponent>
  <Button>Button</Button>
</ExampleComponent>
```

I'm getting this Typescript error and I can't seem to figure it out.

```
Property '__docgenInfo' does not exist on type 'string | JSXElementConstructor<any>'. Property '__docgenInfo' does not exist on type string'. ts(2339)
```

What type am I supposed to cast child to so I can get rid of this error?

Answer (score 0):

`child.type` returns a string or a JSXElementConstructor, and neither have a `_docgenInfo` property in any implementation I have been able to find. (In fact, searching '_docgenInfo' just brings you to this question, with few other results. The other result points me at Storybook, but I know nothing about that library/framework, so this answer ignores that information.)

At any rate, the displayName property is [primarily used for debugging](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname). It's recommended you use an inline class or identifier to do something like

```
  const hasButtons = React.Children.toArray(children).some(
    (child) => React.isValidElement(child) && child.props.id.includes("valid")
  );
```

If you are bound and determined to use the displayName property, I did manage to get a working version by casting the type property on the child to `FunctionalComponent` (because the type is itself a React-forwarded ref, or something; it's *technically* a valid mapping, but very sketchy) as such:

```
  const hasDisplayNameButton = React.Children.toArray(children).some(
    (child) => {
      if (React.isValidElement(child)) {
        let t = child.type as React.FunctionComponent;
        return t.displayName === "Button";
      }
      return false;
  });
```

Again, though, I think this usage of the displayName property is discouraged, though I can't find sources to back it up.